# merge two files with nvim -d or vimdiff

Tags: merge, neovim, vimdiff

Yesterday the arch community announced the successful migration to git. Congrats at this point.

Reading the [news article](https://archlinux.org/news/git-migration-completed/) and the steps to use the new repositories I stumbled over the lines "merge the pacman pacnew `/etc/pacman.conf.pacnew` file".

I compared the two files (my existing and the new one) with `nvim -d` (or `vimdiff`) and thought is it possible to merge the files like I am used to within a git repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is from Fedora/Centos where rpm might produce `*.rpmsave` or `*.rpmnew` files, but I am assuming `*.pacnew` files behave in the exact same way.

---

> and thought is it possible to merge the files like I am used to within a git repository?

Yes it is. It requires a little bit of setup but it is absolutely doable.

## Step 1, Install etckeeper

[Etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/) is a program that

> hooks into package managers like apt, yum, dnf or pacman to automatically commit changes made to `/etc` during package upgrades.

**THIS IS PROGRAM THAT EVERYONE SHOULD INSTALL, independently of plans of using git merge**.

Etckeeper has had full support for Arch [since 2021](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/todo/__91__Patch__93___Support_Pacman_5.x_hooks/).

## Step 2, create an additional worktree for `/etc`

### Worktree in general

When you clone or initializes a repository with git you end up having the repo object storage where git stores commits in the `.git` directory, the index/staging/cache which also is stored in `.git` and a working directory which contains the files corresponding to the current commit. And there is a one to one relation between them.

However git supports connecting multiple working directories to the same repo object storage through the [worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) command. The additional worktrees shares the original `.git` directory but gets their own indexes, and the files are checked out in different directories. Only one single worktree can check out a given branch (although you can of course check out any specific commit, or use a mirroring branch).

Typical use cases for creating additional worktrees are for instance

- [running git test](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test#best-practice-use-git-test-in-a-linked-worktree)
- check out an old version where you want to be able to compare the old version towards the current version for multiple files at once (difftool only lets you compare one file at the time)
- you have a rebase with conflicts ongoing that you do not want to abandon while you need to create a fix on a different branch before that work is finished.

### Worktree for storing the contents of `/etc`

If you use `/etc` as your worktree when doing interactive rebase, then notice that git checks out older commits, and thus `/etc` suddenly contains old versions of various config files. This not unlikely to represent a problem for some services. And when there is a conflicts where git inserts the "<<<<<"/">>>>>" markers, you will have config files that definitely have invalid syntax/content which is unlikely to not represent a problem.

So for these reasons, you should consider `/etc` as the *production system* that you normally do not touch and rather create an additional worktree as the *staging system* where you are free to break and make modifications to.

```bash
cd /etc
git worktree add /root/etc-worktree worktree-main main
cd /root/etc-worktree
```

## Step 3, taking advantage of git for merging

In order to make use of git's merge power you need to keep your own changes separate from the upstream changes on separate branches (this sounds more complicated than it actually is). By having a branch which contains the upstream changes, you can then merge this branch and git is able to use its merge algorithm properly.

You only need to do this for files that end up producing `.pacnew` or `.rpmnew` files and you can do this retroactively, so it is fine to just start with one `main` branch and one `worktree-main` branch, and add upstream branches as needed over time.

You need one branch per file with upstream changes you want to merge (e.g. this only applies to files that you have made local changes to which then prevents the package manager to update).

### Example

One of my machines started out being installed with Fedora 26 in 2017. Why do I know that? Because etckeeper is the second program to install on my list of what to do on a new machine (only installing a full vim version has higher priority), and the first commit which `/etc/hosts` is present in has commit message "Fresh install of Fedora 26". Did I mention how awesome etckeeper is?

Over time I have added a few entries to `/etc/hosts` (and thanks to etckeeper I know exactly when!). The initial `hosts` from Fedora 26 only contained two lines, but then in September 2022 (how do I know when?...) an update to the `setup` package came with a new `hosts` file which contained 5 additional comment lines. Since I had modified `hosts` this new version ended up as `/etc/hosts.rpmnew`.

So this is how I handled that update:

I ran `git log -p hosts` to figure out what the newest commit before I started modifying it was. It was actually commit 1d49be6b *Fresh install of Fedora 26*. So that is the starting point for the upstream update branch.

My branch naming policy is to prefix all such upstream branches with `rpmnew` since `*.rpmnew` files will be the source for the content of those. You can decide to use the full path in the branch or just the file name. For some cases like `/etc/mock/default.cfg` using `rpmnew/mock/default.cfg` is obviously a much better choice than `rpmnew/default.cfg` while using `rpmnew/sshd_config` for `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` might be ok, just make a choice (where a hybrid approach is a possibility).

So with that in mind, I created a `rpmnew/hosts` branch and updated it with the new `hosts.rpmnew` content.

```bash
cd /root/etc-worktree
git branch rpmnew/hosts 1d49be6b
git switch rpmnew/hosts
cp /etc/hosts.rpmnew hosts
git add hosts
git commit -m /etc/hosts.rpmnew
rm /etc/hosts.rpmnew
```

Notice that this resets the worktree's content back to 2017, but that's fine because is not used for anything else. If I had worked directly in `/etc` that would have been a huge problem.

So the upstream changes branch is updated and I can then merge it into the `main` branch (via `worktree-main` first).

```bash
cd /root/etc-worktree
git switch worktree-main
git merge --ff main  # `worktree-main` should strictly follow `main` and only
                     # occasionally be ahead when doing a merge.
git merge rpmnew/hosts
```

The last merge command might result in conflicts, and if so you need to resolve those. I highly recommend [using KDiff3 for conflict resolution](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3).

After the merge is done then `worktree-main` is one merge commit ahead of `main`. This one we want to update `/etc` to use.

```bash
cd /etc
git switch main
git merge --ff worktree-main
```

and that's it. `/etc` was moved forward from whatever *today's content* was to *today's content plus an update to `hosts`* and git made use of its merge functionality along the way.

Comment: Wow, this does not answer my question in the first place, but sounds probably like the solution for the other problem (manually creating temporary baks to update /etc). Most of what you talked about I am familiar with, but `worktree` and `etckeeper` are new for me. I always wanted too use git for system configs. I definitly try this workflow.

Comment: I used KDiff3 in the past, but never understood the 3-Way merge it always confused me, what which file is. The other problem: Is KDiff3 also remote capable? This is the point why I started the question with vimdiff, because it is the tool I have available on all my remote machines.

Comment: KDiff3 is possible to run remotely, just run `ssh` with [`-X` or `-Y` option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35512/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-y-trusted-x11-forwarding-and-ssh-x-u).

Comment: Now I am testing this approach I struggled with the creation of the worktree:
If I use your command I prompted with the usage info of `git worktree`. If I use `git worktree add /root/etc-worktree main` or `worktree-main` I got invalid reference.

Comment: @MaKaNu Maybe you have not configured the default branch to be `main` in git.

Comment: yes this was the case it was the old "master" but still the usage page. It worked if I only used the path, which probably used inherently the HEAD branch and named the worktree "etc-worktree"

Answer (score -2):

While writing this question I realized, I could do what everybody is doing these days and ask the dump AI. Since I didn't found an answer to my problem, I thought: Why not test was the AI is saying an provide the answer for future readers.

So this is what the AI told me to do if I want to merge two files. I describe it with the example for the `pacman.conf`:

open the two files in diff mode:

```bash
sudo cp /etc/pacman.conf /etc/pacman.conf.bak

sudo vimdiff /etc/pacman.conf /etc/pacman.conf.pacnew
```

or

```bash
sudo nvim -d /etc/pacman.conf /etc/pacman.conf.pacnew
```

To navigate between the various diffs use the following commands:

```bash
]c   # move the cursor down to the next diff
[c   # move the cursor up to the previous diff
```

To merge the entries at a diff use the following commands:

```bash
do   # merge the content of right file to left file (diff obtain)
dp   # merge the content of left file to right file (diff put)
```

I must mention that at the end something happened, which I didn't expected:

If the last diff create changes which makes the last lines equal (or the complete file equal) the diff will collapse the last lines. This might be a bit irritating at the first try.