# What is the reason etckeeper does not mention worktree

Tags: git, git-worktree

After starting learning about `etckeeper` after my last question [merge two files with nvim -d or vimdiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304098) I wondered the following:

The approach with a staging `worktree` explained by https://stackoverflow.com/users/23118/hlovdal sounded reasonable. Reading the `etckeeper` tutorial it seems they also follow the idea of a staging area but describe it with `clone` instead of `worktree`.

The only reason which makes sense for me, that other VCS do not have the capability of `worktrees` like git has and they decided to explain an approach with a more common tool/command?

Am I right with hypothesis or are there reasons they used `clone` instead of `worktree`?

Comment: Ask Joey Hess. .